# Watin does not work on my TFS build machine

Tags: internet-explorer, tfs, watin, specflow

I have been trying to get this working for a while, but I can't seem to get my Watin tests run on TFS. They seem to work on my dev account.

I have a TFS user that runs all the tests in my solution. All test pass, but the Watin tests fail.

I obtain the following errors:

```
WatiN.Core.Exceptions.RunScriptException: RunScript failed ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

The Error stack is:

```
mshtml.HTMLWindow2Class.IHTMLWindow2_execScript(String code, String language)
WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEUtils.RunScript(String scriptCode, String language, IHTMLWindow2 window)
WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEUtils.RunScript(String scriptCode, String language, IHTMLWindow2 window)
WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEElement.GetJavaScriptElementReference()
WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEFireEventHandler.CreateJavaScriptFireEventCode(NameValueCollection eventObjectProperties, String eventName)
WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEFireEventHandler.FireEvent(String eventName, NameValueCollection eventProperties, Boolean noWait)
WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEElement.FireEvent(String eventName, NameValueCollection eventProperties)
WatiN.Core.Element.FireEvent(String eventName, Boolean waitForComplete, NameValueCollection eventProperties)
WatiN.Core.Element.FireEvent(String eventName)
WatiN.Core.Element.Focus()
WatiN.Core.Actions.TypeTextAction.TypeAppendClearText(String value, Boolean append, Boolean clear)
WatiN.Core.Actions.TypeTextAction.TypeText(String value)
WatiN.Core.TextField.TypeText(String value)
```

Any ideas on where to start looking?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the build service is setup to run as an interactive process, more info in [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/05/26/coded-ui-test-in-a-team-build.aspx) post. It's about Coded UI, but it might be relevant.

Also, check that your user account has permissions to run interactive processes (can you logon as it), and isn't secured as a service only user.

[image: TFS build]

Comment: I get the following error:
"The working folder d:\Build\1\MyProject\Watin Test\Sources is already in use by the workspace 8_1_appsdev_build;Domain\BUILD_MACHINE$ on computer BUILD_MACHINE."
Any idea why the error appears? All users are logged out from the build machine.

Comment: This should really be another question but... Logon to your build server as the account the build server runs as, and open VS. File->Source Control->Workspaces and delete the one you mentioned above.