# TFS as interactive process does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, workspace

Following on from my previous question ( [Watin does not work on my TFS build machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126068/watin-does-not-work-on-my-tfs-build-machine) ), I have made my TFS build an interactive process.

I do however, get the following error when I run the build:

```
The working folder d:\Build\Sources is already in use by the workspace 8_1_appsdev_build;myUserAccount$ on computer myComputerName.
```

After some research, it seems that I need to delete my workspaces. If tried to list my workspaces with the following command, but the results indicate that I do not have any workspaces. Not sure what I am missing. Any ideas?

**View workspaces command:**

```
tf workspaces /computer: myComputerName /owner:*

No workspace matching *;* on computer myComputerName found in Team 
Foundation Server http://myComputerName:8080/tfs/production.
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same error when trying to add to my TFS and no workspaces is snown using the tf command line tool. No idea how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can find and delete the workspace by opening Visual Studio on build servers with same account or by using workspace sidekicks from [TFS Sidekicks tool](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessary have to delete the workspace, something apparently going wrong here.
The message is just telling you that you attempt to create a new workspace with a mapping that is already used by another workspace.

For instance:

- **WorkspaceA** already exists, it has one mapping: $\ to c:\pipo
- Any attempt to create a **WorkspaceB** with a mapping that use c:\pipo (or a subfolder) will failed.

Maybe you create a previous Build Definition that use the same local path as the one you're trying to run: this will fail the same way.

To sum up there's per default one Workspace per Build Definition with the ability to make it persistent or not (mainly for speed optimization during the get of files), make sure two build definition don't use the same path in local.

Answer (score 0):

`tf workspaces` looks at the *workspace cache* file to provide output.  If you're running `tf` as yourself, you will only see workspaces that *you* have connected to.  Thus, you would not see the build user's workspaces (regardless of the `/owner` option, which simply acts as a filter.)

Either run `tf workspaces` as the build user, or use the `/collection` argument to force a query of the workspaces on the server, bypassing the cache.